# Understanding Localized Rings mod an ideal.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

Hi guys I am working with Fulton's book and I am trying to understand for myself the elements of two rings.

$O_p(\mathbb{A}^n)/JO_p(\mathbb{A}^n)$  and $O_p(V)/\bar{J}O_p(V)$

Where $I = \mathbb{I}(\mathbb{V}) \subset \mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3,..x_n]$ and $p \in V$ and J is an ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3,..x_n]$ that contains I. Using $\bar{J}$ to denote the image of J in the coordinate ring $K(V)$.

So what I think is that if $\psi \in O_p(\mathbb{A}^n)/JO_p(\mathbb{A}^n)$
Then $ \psi = \frac{f}{g}$ such that $f(p)=0$ if and only if $\psi = 0$ in $O_p(\mathbb{A}^n)/JO_p(\mathbb{A}^n)$.

The other ring is exactly the same and we can see this by defining a ring homomorphism between the two;
Say $F :O_p(\mathbb{A}^n)/JO_p(\mathbb{A}^n) \rightarrow O_p(V)/\bar{J}O_p(V)$
by  $F(\frac{f}{g})= \frac{f}{g}$ mod I.

Does this seem okay? Please comment and help me understand the two rings as in what are the elements that live in them. Also it is true that those rings are isomorphic right?